# jquery delete table row on click on check box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which is dynamically created , there is a checkbox in each row of the table, when user click that checkbox the whole row of the dynamically created table needs to deleted.

Comment: Can give a more accurate answer if you include a snippet of the HTML for the table/checkbox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("tr input:checkbox").live("click", function(){ 
    $(this).closest("tr").remove(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table').delegate('tr input:checkbox', 'click', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/russcam/uyL3F/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $(".yourCheckboxClass").change(event){
        function(){
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply this specific table, like this.

```
$("#yourtableID  tr").live("click", function(){ 
    $(this).closest("tr").remove(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table.grid input:checkbox').change(function(){
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: is the ":checked" filter necessary? I guess it depends if things are checked by default. Pinu's UI should be very aggravating...

Comment: do we need to give the id of the table?

Comment: I added a class selector to the table. Probably want this for all `grids`. @hunter - i think i had the logic reversed. But yes depending on the default state it may not be necessary.